# aplay with pipewire

Tags: audio, pipewire, alma-linux, mediaplayer

I am running AlmaLinux 9 and have a problem playing back audio using 'aplay'.   I have a service running as root, and when it tries to play the audio file I get error:

```
aplay: main:831: audio open error: Host is down
```

If I login as root and play the file it works fine.  What's the difference and how do I fix this?